# GUI Text element disappears when I am trying to change its position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote the following code to keep the score of my game.

```
    private GameObject scoreobject;
    private int score;
    public void InstantiateScore()
    {
        score = 0;
        scoreobject = GameObject.Find("scoretext");
        //scoreobject.transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
    public void UpdateScore(){
        score++;
        scoreobject = GameObject.Find("scoretext");
        if (scoreobject)
        {
            scoreobject.guiText.text = score.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The problem is in the commented line `scoreobject.transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);`. When I am trying to change the position of my scoreobject, the object is not appeared on the screen.

Comment: Did you parent the scoreobject into some hierarchies? If so you should try scoreobject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

Comment: It may be because the position is in screen coordinates... Meaning that the screen will be measured from 0 - 1 on both the x and y axis... So x=0.5 y=0.5 then your text will be exactly in the middle...